# What is the form of energy that is forming while lifting a suitcase

Tags: energy, energy-conservation

If I am lifting a heavy suitcase and I am not moving at all. Abviously I am not doing work because I am not moving or rising the suitcase up and down. But abviously I am losing chemical  energy since I am getting tired, so what form the chemical has transformed to. Is it heat or what. Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about biology, not physics.

Comment: I am sorry I misused some terms, so i edited the question. Thank you.